# How to create smart Group based on BuddyPress profile field data?

Tags: wordpress, smartgroups, location, buddypress

We have a WordPress site with BuddyPress, and a few thousand members around the world. Our BuddyPress profile fields include "City", which is saved in wp_bp_xprofile_data (and assigned a geocode saved as a meta_value in wp_bp_xprofile_meta).

I'd like to create smart groups for mailing lists based on the member's location, but I'm not sure where to start, and I'm pretty inexperienced at coding...

1) Is there a built in way to query for xprofile data while creating a smart group?  Or to automatically sync specific data from BP tables with CiviCRM contact info?

2) Are there any WordPress plugins which could do this?  Every time I try to search, all I find is stuff to sync BP Groups to civi, but our members are not organized into BP groups in any way that would be useful for this.

Thanks!

Comment: You are (or someone is) going to need to code this as I can't think of a plugin that will do this for you.